# Sending POST through Requests with Cookies and Authentication

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to write a simple script that checks for availability at a particular restaurant at Disney World.  I've traced the activities of the website to find that it needs to have a POST sent to it with some specific details and I think some form of authentication.  I've got code that runs and returns a result, but it isn't the result that I am looking. The return seems to be a redirect to the main Disney page and not the query for which I am asking.  Anyone know what I am missing in this procedure?

My current strategy is to start a session with requests and do an initial get from the website which I then capture the cookies and this one identifier (pep_csrf) that is later used in the post.  That all seems to work fine, but when I actually do the post, I don't get the data I'm expecting.

```
import requests
import urllib

url = "https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/dining/"
url2 = "https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/dining/finder/dining-availability"

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'})

tokenRequest = session.get(url)
start = tokenRequest.content.find('''id="pep_csrf"''')
pep = tokenRequest.content[start+21:tokenRequest.content.find('>',start+22)-1]
sessionCookies = tokenRequest.cookies


payload = {
'pep_csrf': pep,
'searchDate': '2015-11-13',
'skipPricing': 'true',
'searchTime':'80000714',
'partySize':'2',
'id':'293704;entityType=restaurant',
'type':'dining'
}

raw = urllib.urlencode(payload)
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'referer': 'https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/dining/',

}
result = session.post(url2, data=raw, cookies=sessionCookies,   headers=headers)

print result.content
```

Comment: It has been a long time since this was asked. I was not able to reproduce your problem, as when I try your code, I get an error at: tokenRequest.content.find('''id="pep_csrf"'''.  The error says that it is expecting byte or integer data input not a string.     Anyway were you ever able to get into the Disney system without perpetual redirects, and do you have any advice?

Comment: Hi!  I actually was able to at one point by using a project I found on GitHub, but it, unfortunately, eventually broke too and then I lost interest and didn't need to do this any more.  There are projects on GitHub that use Selenium to fake a human doing it which I have also tried in the past and had some success with.

Comment: thanks @otictac1!  I will check out Selenium...